# Armature does not want to be animated

Tags: animation, armature

I have now for a few hours been trying to animate one set of bones but with no success. I animated one set before and that worked but with this one it does not want to be animated.

[image]

I have placed the bones in one position and then moved the time line indicator to frame 0 and then pressed "i" and captured the location. Then I placed the time line indicator to frame 25 and pressed moved the bones and pressed "i" they show up on the time line but when I render it or move the time line indicator it does not show the recorded animation.

I have no idea why it does not work I tried different methods, with using the auto record button but that did also not work.

With kind regards,
Remmert

Comment: if, for example, you've rotated your bone, i > Location won't save the rotation, so are your sure you've saved the right data? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You are totally correct. i just had an other look and i indeed logged the wrong data I logged the location data instead of the rotation. Thank you so much

Comment: what you can do to avoid that is to always save LocRotScale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, for example, you've rotated your bone, <kbd>i</kbd> > *Location* won't save the rotation but only the location, so you need to make sure that you've keyframed the right data.

What you can do to avoid that is to always save *LocRotScale*.

Answer (score 0):

> What you can do to avoid that is to always save LocRotScale.

This definitely works, and is probably the simplest way to ensure that the right channels get keyed. Later on, though, in future projects, perhaps, you may find that this solution creates a lot of extra keyframes, and that this clutters up your timeline. If you ever experience this, you might consider using the keyset labeled "Available" instead of "LocRotScale". What Available does is keyframe only the channels which have already received keyframes. Naturally, this means that nothing happens when pressing 'i' if no keyframes have already been set. The first keys will always have to be set manually. But once you have all the desired channels keyed, Available works as good as LocRotScale. Moreover, it will NEVER key channels you don't want keyed, meaning that you can get all the convenience of LocRotScale while also keeping the number of keyframes you are creating to a minimum.

Comment: Thank you a lot for that explanation, I will definitely keep that in mind when I will do more with animation in blender. Very is full tip.